# How can I Convert a ReadonlyArray<any> to any[]?

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-conversion

Some native angular functions return a ReadonlyArray. Some native angular callbacks pass ReadonlyArrays. Since my typescript code may be called in many ways, I don't want to require all arrays passed to my functions be ReadonlyArrays.

Hence I need to convert a ReadonlyArray to a javascript native array, [].

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The simplest way to convert the `ReadonlyArray<any>` to `any[]` is to use one of the available methods of `ReadonlyArray`.

For this we will use `concat()`. Calling concat with no parameters on a `ReadonlyArray` will return an `[]`.

N.B. The same can be achieved with `let newArray = [...ReadonlyArray]` 
([spread operator](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_spread_operator.asp)); it creates a copy of each item.

Note: You can view other [ReadonlyArray members here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/cd09cbbd5e5e483d5441e41d0acbcde9e868af60/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1062).

Comment: N.B. You can achive the same with `let newArray = [...ReadonlyArray]`, it creates a copy of each item.

Comment: How is the performance with the spread operator?

Comment: I haven't measured it, but I would assume that the spread operator internally uses concat() so I'd expect that  the performance is the same.

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer and add it, if you'd like the points/credit.