# Converting a ReadonlyArray<any> to a usual mutable array []?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In some cases `Angular` functions and callbacks return a `ReadonlyArray`. But array should be used as usual one, as I don't use some immutable structures like ones in `Redux`.

So how can I convert `ReadonlyArray` to a JavaScript native array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I Convert a ReadonlyArray<any> to any\[\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54188364/how-can-i-convert-a-readonlyarrayany-to-any)

Comment: `ReadonlyArray` is just an interface over native arrays that excludes mutating members. The underlying implementation is still a native array so you could just assert it as such.

Answer (score 11):

In this case `.concat()` or `.slice()` without parameters can be used.
they create new array based on immutable one. It is kind of shallow copy.
Something similar:
[How can I Convert a ReadonlyArray<any> to any[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54188364/how-can-i-convert-a-readonlyarrayany-to-any)

Comment: You probably meant `slice()` here.